# How to specify the statsd client port?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, statsd, pcf

I have one java spring boot application deployed on pcf environment. I have used statsd client library to send metrics to the statsd server. So the problem is how do I specify host and port in statsd client so that it can send metrics.

```
        public StatsDClient statsDClient(
        @Value("${metrics.statsd.host:localhost}") String host,
        @Value("${metrics.statsd.port:8125}") int port,
        @Value("${metrics.prefix:example.app}") String prefix
) {
    return new NonBlockingStatsDClient(prefix, host, port);
}
```

I have to specify the host and port for the PCF deployed app, How to do it ?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you mean. You should be able to set those properties in `application.properties` or `application.yml`, depending on which one you're using. You would need to set `metrics.statsd.host=<blah>` and `metrics.statsd.port=<blah>`. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey, I want to do it on PCF(Pivotal Cloud Foundry), as PCF does not provide specific IP and port. So how should I do it ?

Comment: I don't know anything about statsd, but if it's not HTTP based and you need to run the server on PCF then you need to either use TCP routes or you need to do it over the container to container network. TCP routes would be if you need to accept external connections to your server, and container to container would work if you're only accepting connections between apps running on PCF. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey,Thank you for the reply, as Statsd Client uses UDP packets to send data to my statsd server so what should I use ? Will Container to container method work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding it correctly you have two apps running in PCF.

1. One Spring boot app- which you are calling some client app.
2. Second is your statsd server

and you need to establish a communication between these two.

As Daniel mentioned in comment you have two ways to do it.

1. [HTTP/TCP](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#http-vs-tcp-routes)
2. [Internal Route](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes)

Problem with option 1 is that you may not be able to use that with host and port separately as PCF internally doing that.

I'd recommended to use the second option- Internal route which gives you clear host name and port which you need to configure in client app.
Here are the steps you can follow to configure the Container-to-Container networking

1. Add a new route to your server app -i.e. `app1.apps.internal`
2. Create network policy with client and server app - [link](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/add-network-policy.html)
3. Define property in config server or code-base whatever process you are using for property externalization - Your final URL would look like: `app1.apps.internal:8080`

Comment: Thank you so much, This Worked.. I almost wasted one week on this..But finally it worked.